# Why an empty or not biblatex \DeclareSourcemap is removing my bibliography Access Date entry?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, abnt, biblatex-sourcemap

Recently I noticed my `Access Date` bibliography entry was missing. After searching throughout my code, I figured out it was caused because of `\DeclareSourcemap`.

On the next example build with an empty `\DeclareSourcemap{}`, the `Access Date` bibliography entry will be removed:

[image]

But if you remove the line `\DeclareSourcemap{}`, then, the `Access Date` field shows up correctly:

[image]

How to stop the `\DeclareSourcemap{}` command from removing my `Access Date` bibliography entry?

It does not matter what I do. For example, if I declare an empty `\DeclareSourcemap`, like this:

```latex
\DeclareSourcemap{}
```

My `Access Date` bibliography will be removed.

If I let my original `\DeclareSourcemap`:

```latex
\DeclareSourcemap
{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]
  {
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=pagetotal, null]
    }
    \map
    {
      \pertype{inproceedings}
      \step[fieldset=venue, null]
      \step[fieldset=eventdate, null]
      \step[fieldset=eventtitle, null]
      \step[fieldset=isbn, null]
      \step[fieldset=volume, null]
    }
  }
}
```

My `Access Date` bibliography entry still being removed.

```latex
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@mvbook{assis08,
    author = {Machado de Assis},
    title = {Obra completa em quatro volumes},
    year = {2008},
    editor = {Aluizio Leite and Ana Lima Cecilio and Heloisa Jahn},
    editortype = {organizer},
    edition = {2},
    volumes = {4},
    publisher = {Nova Fronteira},
    location = {Rio de Janeiro},
    series = {Biblioteca luso-brasileira. Série brasileira brasileira brasiled},
    urlaccessdate = {2018-02-17},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\PassOptionsToPackage{brazil,main=english,spanish,french}{babel}
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,english]{abntex2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=abnt,repeatfields=true,backend=biber,backref=true]{biblatex}
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{\let\uppercase\relax}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSourcemap{} % <-- Remove this and the `Access Date` will show up correctly

\begin{document}
Citing \cite{assis08}. \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are running an outdated version of `biblatex` that does not allow for multiple `\DeclareSourcemap`s. This restriction was lifted in version 3.11 (2018-02-20) of `biblatex`, see https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/227.

`urlaccessdate` is not the standard `biblatex` field for the URL access date. The standard field would be `urldate`. For backwards compatibility with `abntex2cite` `biblatex-abnt` remaps `urlaccessdate` and other fields to their `biblatex`-equivalents in a `\DeclareSourcemap`.

In your outdated `biblatex` there can be only one sourcemap and the document-level sourcemap in your preamble overwrites the style-level sourcemap. That's why there was `\DeclareStyleSourcemap` that styles could use without interfering with user-level maps.

If you update `biblatex` everything will work as expected. `biblatex-abnt` should be using `DeclareStyleSourcemap`, though, see https://github.com/abntex/biblatex-abnt/pull/56.

As a temporary workaround you can either get the fixed `abnt.bbx` from https://github.com/abntex/biblatex-abnt/pull/56 or combine your sourcemap and the style sourcemap to

```
\DeclareSourcemap{%% >>>2
  % This maps some fields used in abntex2cite to biblatex fields.
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{%
    \map{%
      \step[fieldsource=conference-number,fieldtarget=number]%
      \step[fieldsource=conference-year,fieldtarget=eventdate]%
      \step[fieldsource=conference-location,fieldtarget=venue]%
      \step[fieldsource=conference-number,fieldtarget=number]%
      \step[fieldsource=org-short,fieldtarget=shortauthor]%
      \step[fieldsource=urlaccessdate,fieldtarget=urldate]%
      \step[fieldsource=year-presented,fieldtarget=eventyear]%
      \step[fieldsource=furtherresp,fieldtarget=titleaddon]%
      \step[typesource=journalpart,typetarget=supperiodical]%
    }%
    \map[overwrite=false]{%
          \step[fieldsource=reprinted-from, final]%
          \step[fieldset=related, origfieldval]%
    }%
    \map[overwrite=false]{%
          \step[fieldsource=reprinted-text, final]%
          \step[fieldset=relatedtype, fieldvalue={reprintfrom}]%
    }%
    \map{%
          \pertype{patent}% Use the organization as sourcekey for patents
          \step[fieldsource=organization, final]%
          \step[fieldset=sortkey, origfieldval]%
    }%
    \map[overwrite=false]{%
      \pertype{thesis}%
      \pertype{phdthesis}%
      \pertype{mastersthesis}%
      \pertype{monography}%
      \step[fieldset=bookpagination, fieldvalue={sheet}]%
    }%
    \map{
      \step[fieldset=pagetotal, null]
    }
    \map
    {
      \pertype{inproceedings}
      \step[fieldset=venue, null]
      \step[fieldset=eventdate, null]
      \step[fieldset=eventtitle, null]
      \step[fieldset=isbn, null]
      \step[fieldset=volume, null]
    }
  }%
}% <<<2
```

in your document.